# "same as" or "the same as"?

Tags: grammar

What is the correct use of "same as" in the following sentences?

> Additionally, records have shown that increasing the data size to 1MB and keeping the access latency the same as a small data set, reduces the throughput
>
> Additionally, records have shown that increasing the data size to 1MB and keeping the access latency, same as a small data set reduces the throughput

Comment: those are *too little* sentences to guess and answer! :)

Comment: updated the examples

Comment: **generally**, 'same' takes the definite article. The logic is we must have defined something earlier before introducing 'same'. :)

Comment: I didn't understand what you said

Comment: I mean in most of the cases we always use the definite article. 'the same' is correct.

Comment: @mahmood: You did change the commas in your examples - this changes the meaning. Could you perhaps check your question? And: I feel Maulik V's comment is a bit too simplified, there are instances where "same" could be used w.o. "the".

Comment: @Stephie I think *the* before *same* is almost always needed in written text and when there is no comma involved before *same* (just like the sentence in the question). But in spoken you can easily omit that *the* before *same*.

Answer (score 2):

"the" is almost always used with "same". I think this sentence can be rephrased in a better way as follows:

Additionally, records have shown that increasing the data size to 1MB and keeping the access latency reduces the throughput the same as a small data set (does).

Comment: Is it possible to say "keeping the access latency reduces the throughput _**as the same way as**_ a small data set does"?

Comment: It's more idiomatic if you say ........in the same way as a small data set does.